# Not able to login in Magento Frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, login, session, cookie

We currently can't login in the Magento frontend with any browser except **internet explorer**.

even creating a new customer account and trying to log in with it did not work

we also cleared the Magento session cache and tried again

Comment: could you clarify that a little? I created a new account in frontend and was able to log in. So if you can't there must be another relevant factor

Comment: is it ?  , it did t worked for me

Comment: is it redirecting to my account page ?

Comment: it was actually the last time I think, now it's redirecting me to the homepage. But there is a backend configuration for this I think

Comment: please inform what mistake i done ? so i can  correct in backend

Comment: I'm not sure. So you can't actually log in in frontend? Also with a completely new account?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: that's weird. Since I can't reconstruct the issue, it would be good if you could provide some additional information in your question. Did you delete your cookies for the site in your Browser? Currently I have to assume that it's a local issue because it's working for me (actually with Firefox but the Browser should not make a difference here except for it's saved cookies)

Comment: yes it didt worked, so i cleared sesssion and cache, still didt worked, deleted browser history from opera , didt worked

Comment: working in opera now.....

Comment: please post an answer that it will work after clearing browser history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from comments in the question:

This was a browser cache/cookies related Problem.

Even clearing the Magento session cache did not resolve the Problem.

I assume that clearing the frontend cookie from the browser did the trick. This might have been an external module doing something with the frontend cookie.